# What are the constraints on $\alpha$ so that $AX=B$ has a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I found the following problem and I'm a little confused.

> Consider $$A=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> 3 & 2 & -1 & 5 \\
> 1 & -1 & 2 & 2\\
> 0 & 5 & 7 & \alpha \end{array} \right)$$ and $$B=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> 0 & 3  \\
> 0 & -1 \\
> 0 & 6 \end{array} \right)$$
>
> What are the constraints on $\alpha$ so that the matrix equation $AX=B$ has solution?

Since neither $A$ nor $B$ are square, I can't get their inverses. Is the problem wrong?

Comment: Try it like this. $(AX_1, AX_2) = (B_1, B_2)$, The notation $X_1$ is 1st column of the matrix X. Then it is changed into solving two different linear equations.

Comment: Do you know how to answer the question if instead $B=\begin{bmatrix}3\\-1\\6\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fourth column, notice that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 2\\ 0 & 5 & 7  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 2\\ 0 & 5 & 7  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \frac15 \\ \frac65 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ -1 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Can you comment on whether $\alpha$ influence existence of solutions?

Are you able to construct an $X$ for the original problem?

Remark:

In general, you might like to perform row operations on the system of equations.

Tips:

If $A_1$ is a matrix that consists of some columns of $A$ and $A_1$ is non-singular, the solution to $AX=B$ always exist. Do you see why?

Comment: I was actually thinking of something simpler, for those $x$ that doesn't corresponds to columns in $A_1$, set them to zero. We just solve the system $A_1Y=B$, of which you can do it by nonsingularity of $A_1$.

Comment: hmmm the theorem looks a little bit weird. What is the relationship between $M$ and $A$?

Comment: But I'm a little confused,   a)I understand for your comment that $\alpha$ is arbitrary  b)You solved two the equation $Cx_{1}=b_{1}$ and $Cx_{2}=b_{2}$, where $B=\{b_{1},b_{2}\}$. But i can't see how the original problem is solved.

Comment: Here $A$ is the original matrix, and the matrix C are the first three columns of A, i.e, $A=[C|D]$.

Comment: $$[C, D] \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=[Cx_1, Cx_2]=[b_1, b_2]=B$$

Comment: The theorem looks weird, what if $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I Made a big mistake!!! If $AX=B$ and consider $M=[A|B]$ then, a)The system has a solution if and only if $rank(A)=rank(M).$ b)The solution is unique if and only if $rank(A)=rank(M)=n.$

Answer (score 1):

Use **Gauss-Jordan** elimination to find the RREF of the augmented matrix $[\mathrm A \,|\, \mathrm B]$. We have

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc} 3 & 2 & -1 & 5 & 0 & 3\\ 1 & -1 & 2 & 2 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 5 & 7 & \alpha & 0 & 6\end{array} \right]$$

Using [SymPy](http://live.sympy.org),

```
>>> t = symbols('t')
>>> M = Matrix([[3, 2, -1, 5, 0, 3], [1, -1, 2, 2, 0, -1], [0, 5, 7, t, 0, 6]])
>>> M
⎡3  2   -1  5  0  3 ⎤
⎢                   ⎥
⎢1  -1  2   2  0  -1⎥
⎢                   ⎥
⎣0  5   7   t  0  6 ⎦
>>> M.rref()
⎛⎡           3⋅t   123        ⎤           ⎞
⎜⎢1  0  0  - ─── + ───  0  1/5⎥, [0, 1, 2]⎟
⎜⎢            70    70        ⎥           ⎟
⎜⎢                            ⎥           ⎟
⎜⎢           t    1           ⎥           ⎟
⎜⎢0  1  0    ── - ──    0  6/5⎥           ⎟
⎜⎢           10   10          ⎥           ⎟
⎜⎢                            ⎥           ⎟
⎜⎢           t    1           ⎥           ⎟
⎜⎢0  0  1    ── + ──    0   0 ⎥           ⎟
⎝⎣           14   14          ⎦           ⎠
```

We can conclude that the augmented matrix has full row rank. What does that imply?